# To replace but the last occurrence of string in a text

Tags: python, regex, string, replace

Suppose I have this piece of text:

```
Saturday and Sunday and Monday and Tuesday and Wednesday and Thursday and Friday are days of the week.
```

I want all but the last `and` to be replaced with a comma:

```
Saturday, Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday and Friday are days of the week.
```

Is there an easy way to do that in regex? As far as I know, the `replace` method in regex replaces the strings all the way through.

Comment: Not using the Oxford comma, I see.

Comment: Strictly speaking, regular expressions only do matching, and substitution is a feature of the hosting language, usually its string processing facilities.

Comment: This is a bit unreadable. Maybe you could amuse yourself with it.

    "".join(reduce(lambda x , y : x+["and"+y] if len(x)==0 else x+[","+y] ,re.split("and","Saturday and Sunday and Monday and Tuesday and Wednesday and Thursday and Friday are days of the week. ")[::-1],[])[::-1])[1:]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) method has a `count` argument:

> `str.replace(old, new[, count])`
>
> Return a copy of the string with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new. If the optional argument count is given, only the first count occurrences are replaced.

Then, use [`str.count()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) to check how many `and` in the string and then `-1` (because you need the last `and`):

> `str.count(sub[, start[, end]])`
>
> Return the number of non-overlapping occurrences of substring sub in the range `[start, end]`. Optional arguments start and end are interpreted as in slice notation.

Demo:

```
>>> string = 'Saturday and Sunday and Monday and Tuesday and Wednesday and Thursday and Friday are days of the week.'   
>>> string.replace(' and ', ", ", (string.count(' and ')-1))
'Saturday, Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday and Friday are days of the week.  '
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want a regex solution, you could match all the `and`s which are followed by another one later in the string.

```
>>> str='Monday and Tuesday and Wednesday and Thursday and Friday and Saturday and Sunday are the days of the week.'
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(' and (?=.* and )', ', ', str)
'Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday and Sunday are the days of the week.'
```

`(?=`...`)` is a lookahead which makes sure there is a match later in the string without including it in the actual match (so also not in the substitution).  It's sort of like a conditional on the match.

Comment: What will happen to this string: `'Monday and Tuesday and Wednesday and Thursday and Friday and Saturday and Sunday are the days of the week and it is Monday.'`?

Comment: That's easy to find out, isn't it?  Maybe change the `.*` in the lookahead to `[^.?!]*` to never allow it to match past sentence punctuation.  But then how do you deal with inter-sentence abbreviations with a period which isn't a sentence terminator?  You are quickly ending up with [Zawinski's problem](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/223634/what-is-meant-by-now-you-have-two-problems).  For anything beyond simple tokens, regex is probably not a suitable tool.

Comment: But then for this simple problem you could probably restrict it even further, and hope it never matches past a verb, either.  "John and Mary and I went to Buckingham Palace and had a beer."

Comment: As a workaround (that may also fail in some situations), you could limit the number of words between each occurrence of `and`, ie: `' and (?=(?:[^.,?! ]+ ){1,4}and )'`.

Comment: @Mariano John and John's second cousin's husband's dog and I ...? Actually that's a pretty good idea for a limited scope, but you can't solve the general problem with regex.

Comment: @tripleee Indeed, you can't solve the general case with regex. I simply suggested an alternative, which would also fail in some scenarios.